# Duende Identity Server with Blazor WASM hosted and BFF over HTTP for local development

Tags: asp.net-core, http, blazor-webassembly, samesite, duende-identity-server

I am testing Duende Identity Server (v6) with a Blazor WASM (hosted) project, along with the BackEnd For FrontEnd (BFF) Duende also provides.

With HTTPS everything works well.
With HTTP I find several issues. Some are due to browser policies in cookie SameSite (I think), but I cannot have them working, even in Firefox which, afaik, does not enforce the same restriction of using HTTPS that Chromium does when using other sites/domain cookies with policy SameSite set to `None`.

In any case, I am looking for a way to have the flow interaction between my SPA (Blazor WASM hosted) with my Auth Server (Identity Server) running in http for testing purposes, as I would like to dockerize the applications and development certificates are not meant to be used for cross container communication.

Long story short. I have created [this GitLab repository at a specific commit in time](https://gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/sandbox/blazor-wasm-is-bff/-/tree/45a313dea95a2c1619b7d417bf0f938225236bbe) with a solution with 4 basic projects:

1. `Sample.Auth`, the .NET 7 AspNetCore + Duende Identity Server
2. `Sample.Server`, the .NET 7 AspNetCore which serves a Blazor WASM in the root path + Duende BFF
3. `Sample.Client`, the .NET 7 Blazor WASM
4. `Sample.Shared`, the .NET 7 class library shared between blazor client and server, not really needed.

Everything is very standard, but I've just added some parameters in `appsettings.Development.json` and `launchSettings.json` to configure and behave differently depending on whether I want to run both projects with HTTP or with HTTPS.

The question is: **Is there any good configuration that allows me to run both Identity Server and Blazor WASM** (or any SPA I guess) properly, have the user redirected to the Identity Server UI to enter credentials (e.g: `bob/bob` or `alice/alice`) and being redirected back with the secure BFF (i.e: `authorization_code` grant + PKCE) **so that the client app can retrieve it using HTTP?**

As you can see on my code, in addition to

```
options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
```

I've played with settings cookie options in Blazor WASM

```
options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
```

because I've read that in other older questions. But I can't have it working in Firefox or Chrome, and I'm not sure it's even possible with the latest browsers available. Probably HTTPS is a must, even for local development, when dealing with cookie related auth. Is it?

**More info and instructions on how to reproduce and test it**, at the [README.md](https://gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/sandbox/blazor-wasm-is-bff/-/blob/45a313dea95a2c1619b7d417bf0f938225236bbe/README.md) on the shared repo.